# Using arrow function as a method results unexpectedly: MDN's example with [].push.call()

Tags: javascript, arrays, function

Cannot reproduce [MDN's example](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) («Using an object in an array-like fashion») with arrow-function-based method.

```
> let obj = {
... length: 0,
... addEl: el => [].push.call(this, el={}) //default argument
... };
```

It counts something, but… what? It definitely stores the incrementing value somewhere, but where?

```
> obj.addEl();
1
> obj.addEl({});
2
> obj
{ length: 0, addEl: [Function: addEl] } // array function «this» problem?
```

The original variant increments the length the right way, but it also creates new properties. There was nothing about it in the example.

```
addEl: function (el) { [].push.call(this, el) }
...
// the function in work
> anotherObj.addEl();
> anotherObj.addEl('new');
> anotherObj
{ '0': undefined,
  '1': 'new',
  length: 2,
  addEl: [Function: addEl] }
```

Is it ok? If so, I guess, it should be called «creating array-like object», meaning not only the length property, but the numeric keys too. Related, already answered question is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46630390/using-push-call-to-modify-an-objects-length).

Comment: Your arrow function has lexicographically bound `this`.

Comment: Yes, using the object's own `.length` and indexed properties is the expected result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The incrementing value is stored in `window` because arrow functions don’t bind `this`. Their `this` value is that of the enclosing scope, which in this case is the global scope. For example:

```
let obj = {
  length: 0,
  addEl: el => [].push.call(this, el={}) //default argument
};

console.log(obj.addEl());
console.log(window.length);
```

The `window.length` is the incrementing value. The reason `obj.addEl()` returns the incrementing value is because `Array#push` returns the new `length`. And if you log `window[0]`, you’ll get the default argument that was pushed to `this`, which was `window`:

```
> window[0]
< {}
```

The reason why regular function expressions behave differently is because they are bound to the object `obj` so `this` refers to `obj` in a regular function expression opposed to `window` in an arrow function.

Comment: I've expected this answer (see my other comment here, for the answer by @marvel308). But why does the function from the original example adds new properties to the object? Is that correct and why?

Comment: @JulyMorning The very bottom of my answer explains this. Yes that is correct behavior because when you use a regular function expression, `this` is explicitly bound to the calling object. So when you do `obj.addEl()`, `obj` is the `this` value in a regular function expression. Thus, a new numeric property is added to `obj` and the length is increased.

Comment: so, I shouldn't use arrow functions as methods, right?

Comment: @JulyMorning You shouldn’t. The term ‘method’ specifically applies to regular function expressions because regular function expressions actually *bind `this`* thus are bound to objects, which is the definition of a method. (aside from class property arrow functions in ES2017/18-ish).

Answer (score 0):

It is because you are using arrow functions which does not bind this, using a normal function would give you the result.

```
addEl: el => [].push.call(this, el={})
```

**this** in your case refers to the global window object

Comment: explain the downvote

Comment: I didn't do it. However, I've suspected that the problem is connected with `this` context, and arrow functions don't have it. But still I do not know why it's not bound to the object itself. What does this function count? Where is that value?

Comment: it is incrementing windows.length since it calls to increase the value of this, which currently is windows.  If you console.log(windows.length) you will see the value